# Rigidbody.Usegravity on collision enter doesnt work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Im throwing a bomb using physics made by code. For some reason it doesnt detect collision unless my physics stop applying force to the object. in order to bypass it I cancelled the applied force and applied gravity to it on collision enter and put the movement of the bomb to LateUpdate so it will trigger after the OnCollisionEnter but the bomb collides only most of the time with the floor (mesh collision, the floor made with ProBuilder) and not all of the time. the bomb collision detection is set to continuous
Will appreciate all the help, Thanks!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class BombBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] float ExplosionForce = 300;
[SerializeField] float ExplosionRadius;
[SerializeField] float LaunchForceX;
[SerializeField] float LaunchForceY;
[SerializeField] float Delay;
float countdown;
Rigidbody rigidbodyy;
float gravity = 1;
Player player;
bool HasExploded = false;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rigidbodyy = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    player = Player.p;
    GetLaunchForceX();
    countdown = Delay;
}

private void GetLaunchForceX()
{
    
    if (transform.position.x > player.transform.position.x)
    {
        LaunchForceX *= 1;
    }
    else if (transform.position.x < player.transform.position.x)
    {
        LaunchForceX *= -1;
    }
}

private void LateUpdate()
{
    ThrowBomb();
}
private void Update()
{
    countdown -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (countdown <= 0 && !HasExploded)
    {
        ExplodeNearEnemy();
    }
}

private void ThrowBomb()
{
    if (rigidbodyy.useGravity == false)
    {
        Vector3 ThrowDirection = new Vector3(LaunchForceX, LaunchForceY, 0);
        LaunchForceY -= gravity;
        ThrowDirection.y = LaunchForceY;
        transform.Translate(ThrowDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}

private void ExplodeNearEnemy()
{
    Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, ExplosionRadius);
    foreach (Collider collider in colliders)
    {
        if (collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            Rigidbody enemyRB = collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            if (enemyRB != null)
            {
                enemyRB.useGravity = true;
                enemyRB.AddExplosionForce(ExplosionForce, transform.position, ExplosionRadius);
                Destroy(enemyRB.gameObject,1);
            }
        }
    }
    //Destroy(gameObject);
}
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    LaunchForceY = 0;
    LaunchForceX = 0;
    gravity = 0;
    rigidbodyy.useGravity = true;
}
```

}

Comment: You don't want to move a physics based object in `LateUpdate` or `Update` at all but rather in the physics loop `FixedUpdate` ... further you don't want to use the `Transform` component but rather only move it via the `Rigidbody` component!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly understand the problem but it looks like you want to make a Bomb/Granate so why dont you just write a function and use AddForce()?

```
void Thow(Vector3 direction, float strength)
{
    rigidbodyy.AddForce(direction * strength, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

something like this should help as you only need to get the throwing direction and apply a strength then Unity will handle the rest

Or maybe if your bomb doesn't collide with the ground give the ground a rigidbody and set kinematic to true

Answer (score 0):

Use the [MovePosition()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) to move a rigid body if you want colliders etc to work. Teleporting a rigid body by altering the transform directly messes up the physics.

Comment: tried doing `rigidbodyy.MovePosition(transform.position + ThrowDirection * Time.deltaTime);` but it still passes through the floor

if i apply gravity to my bomb object and change the code to `if (rigidbodyy.useGravity == false)` the bomb movement looks jagged